# how to do the Hash (key, value, match) array in R?

Tags: r, merge, match

I have a 2 datasets file A.vcf and B.vcf. 
They all look like

```
A:
col1 col2 col3......
A    11    01010101
B    12    10101010 
C    14    00111000

B:
col1 col2 col3......
A    11    01111111
B    12    10000000
C    13    00000000
```

I want to see do they match by colu2? If yes, my output files only including the overlap part. The output A file have their values. B files have their own values.

```
output_A
A    11    01010101
B    12    10101010 

output_B
A    11    01111111
B    12    10000000
```

I try to use merge function by="col2"

But I found out that the output become:

```
A    11    01010101     A    11    01111111
B    12    10101010     B    12    10000000
```

I try to use inner_joun, match and merge function. But results were not what I want.

I know in perl, it looks like a hash array. I want to know How can I do in R

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything unexpected in your current `merge` results.  What output do you actually want here?

Comment: I want my output look like output_A and output_B files. But my 2 output files already including A    11    01010101     (A    11    01111111 this part from B and I dont want to show in file A)
                            B    12    10101010     (B    12    10000000 this part from A and dont want to show in file B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim mentioned, it's not exactly clear if this is what you're after but: if `col1` doesn't matter, maybe you can just use `%in%`?

```
> A[A$col2 %in% B$col2,]

  col1 col2 col3......
1    A   11    1010101
2    B   12   10101010


> B[B$col2 %in% A$col2,]

  col1 col2 col3......
1    A   11    1111111
2    B   12   10000000
```

#### Data:

```
A <- read.table(text = "col1 col2 col3......
A    11    01010101
                B    12    10101010
                C    14    00111000",
                header = TRUE)

B <- read.table(text = "col1 col2 col3......
                A    11    01111111
                B    12    10000000
                C    13    00000000",
                header = TRUE)
```